# Embed Vimeo video using AngularJS directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, vimeo

I have a partial HTML page in an AngularJS app that I'm trying to add a vimeo video to. This template has an image and play button that fades out on click to show the underlying iFrame. I also want this click trigger to play the video, so that someone doesn't have to press two play buttons.

The div in my partial page template where this is happening [working version of site here](http://bengal.missouri.edu/~wjg2q2/100_ages/app/#/100_Ages/1):

```
<div id="container" >

    <div id="dummy"></div>
    <div id="element">

    <iframe id="player" class="fade {{playerFade}}" ng-src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/{{person.video}}?api=1&amp;player_id=player&amp;wmode=opaque" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

    <img id="person_photo" class="fade {{person_photoFade}}" ng-src="{{person.photo_small}}" ng-src-responsive="[ [ '(min-width: 720px)', '{{person.photo_medium}}' ], [ '(min-width: 960px)', '{{person.photo_large}}' ], [ '(min-width: 1200px)', '{{person.photo_extralarge}}' ] ]" />

    <a id="playButton" ng-click="playing=true"  class="fade {{playButtonFade}}" ><img src="img/furniture/play.png" class="img_play" alt="play button"/></a>
    </div>

</div>
```

Now, I did get this to work once, but that was with a static, non-Angular web page. The code I used to interact with the Vimeo API is something I took from SO#8444240. They were trying to figure out preloading. Since I have so many videos, I'm not interested in that, I just used this code to get my button interacting with my video.

I tried putting this script into my index.html page, but since it is removed from Angular, it doesn't work at all. I think I need a directive. Here is the current script code I have:

```
<script>  

 //INIT Vimeo API

var vimeoPlayers = document.querySelectorAll('#player'),
    player;

for (var i = 0, length = vimeoPlayers.length; i < length; i++) {
    player = vimeoPlayers[i];
    $f(player).addEvent('ready', ready);
}

function addEvent(element, eventName, callback) {
    if (element.addEventListener) {
        element.addEventListener(eventName, callback, false);
    } else {
        element.attachEvent(eventName, callback, false);
    }
}

function ready(player_id) {
    // Keep a reference to Froogaloop for this player
    var container = document.getElementById(player_id).parentNode.parentNode, 
        froogaloop = $f(player_id);

    $('#playButton a').click(function(){

        $('#person_photo').fadeOut('12000');
        froogaloop.api('play');

        return false;   

    });                

}

</script>
```

I've got a directive that controls the playbutton to fade it out (thanks to [wmluke on a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17205596/controller-doesnt-work-after-url-change)) but I don't know how to translate this javascript into a directive. Here is my controller, too.

```
function DetailCtrl($scope, $routeParams, $http) {
  $http.get('person.json').success(function(data) {
    angular.forEach(data, function(person) {
          if (person.id == $routeParams.personId) 
            $scope.person = person;
        });
    });

  $scope.playing = false;

  // Update the *Fade scope attributes whenever the `playing` scope attribute changes
  $scope.$watch('playing', function (playing) {
        $scope.playerFade = playing ? 'in' : '';
        $scope.person_photoFade = playing ? '' : 'in';
        $scope.playButtonFade = playing ? '' : 'in';
  });
```

I tried writing this directive as best I could, but I don't know how to handle the ready calls to Vimeo API. It seems like there is a better way to do it in Angular.

Comment: EDIT: The video at [this link](http://bengal.missouri.edu/~wjg2q2/100_ages/app/#/100_Ages/16) isn't marked private.